# What is the way to do Snapshot Testing without using 'react-test-renderer' library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Currently I am doing React component testing using **@testing-library/react** and **@testing-library/jest-dom**. What is the way to do snapshot testing using above mentioned libraries ?

**Note:** *'react-test-renderer'* is not permissible to use in application.

Comment: Do you read the doc about [render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#render)?